# How do I change the error band in Seaborn relplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, errorbar

Updated: Could someone please guide me to change it to S.E.M. (Standard Error of the Mean)?
[image: sample plot]

Thanks, JohanC

Comment: Did you click on [lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)? Did you read that default the mean is drawn, and a 95% confidence interval is calculated via [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))? When you write "SEM", are you referring to a stochastic estimated mean calculated by bootstrapping?

Comment: Thanks, JohanC! I updated the question.

Comment: No, default it is bootstrapping (a stochastic estimation).  Only if you pass `ci='sd'` you get the standard deviation. With `ci=None` the confidence interval isn't shown.

Comment: My bad!!! Apologies. If I may, is bootstrapping the same as the standard error of the mean?

Comment: I'm not a statistician. I think the bootstrapped interval is one of the ways to estimate the standard error of the mean. If not too much is known about the distribution the bootstrapping is probably the only way to always get a reasonable value.  Other methods can be used when the distribution is known.

Comment: A 68% bootstrap CI (the default is 95%) is ~equivalent to the standard error of the mean. Note that in seaborn 0.12+ you'll be able to do `lineplot(..., errorbar="se")` to get an analytic SEM interval.

Comment: Thanks, mwaskom! I appreciate your comment. 
Seaborn 0.12+ is not yet released, right?